# Changing highmap values dynamically

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this highmap code below and I am looking in a way to pass to it dynamically some values:

```js
let rendermap = Highcharts.mapChart("map-container", {
  chart: {
    map: "custom/world",
  },
  borderColor: "#EEF0EF",
  colors: ["#CBCDCC", "#6b6b6b"],
  mapNavigation: {
    enabled: true,
    enableDoubleClickZoomTo: true,
  },
  mapNavigation: {
    enabled: true,
    buttonOptions: {
      theme: {
        fill: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)",
        "stroke-width": 1,
        stroke: "#fb9718",
        r: 13,
        states: {
          hover: {
            fill: "#fb9718",
          },
          select: {
            stroke: "#039",
            fill: "#fb9718",
          },
        },
      },
      verticalAlign: "top",
      alignValue: "center",
    },
  },
  colorAxis: {
    min: 1,
    max: 1000,
    type: "logarithmic",
  },
  series: [{
    data: mapdata,
    borderColor: "#EEF0EF",
    joinBy: ["iso-a3", "code3"],
    name: "Population density",
    states: {
      hover: {
        color: "#07AABB",
      },
    },
  }, ],
});
```

I want to dynamically change the color option in `colorAxis` for example. Could I just do: `rendermap.colorAxis.amxColor ="#EEF0EF"`. It doesn't seem to work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `update` method, for example:

```
rendermap.update({
  colorAxis: {
    maxColor: "#EEF0EF"
  }
});
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-update/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

Answer (score 0):

That probably occurs because you are mutating the object and the change is not detected in order to re-render.

try this:

```
rendermap = {
   ...rendermap,
   colorAxis: {
      ...rendermap.colorAxis,
      amxColor: "#EEF0EF"
   }
}
```